# Mudar palavra exibida por php

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou pegando uma palavra com uma função do wordpress, `<?php single_cat_title(); ?>`, ela me retorna o nome da categoria a ser exibida na página. Tem como fazer que quando ele retornasse a categoria com id = 1 ou nome = nome1 ele exibisse um outro nome?

Exemplo:

Na página da categoria "NOME123": `<p><?php single_cat_title(); ?></p>`, apareceria "NOME123"

E na página da categoria "EMON321" usando `<p><?php single_cat_title(); ?></p>`, fazer com que exiba qualquer outro nome.

Ta sendo exibido assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Precisava que quando fosse a palavra "Time", aparecesse "Team Supply"
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara não manjo muito de Wordpress, mas a maneira correta seria você editar isso pela administração!

No entanto se quiser marretar com PHP do jeito que propôs, faça o seguinte:

```
<p><?php 
    $seutitulo = single_cat_title( '', false ); // pega o valor sem imprimir na tela
                                                // Documentação dessa função single_cat_title:
                                                //https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/single_cat_title/

    if(strpos($seutitulo, "Time")!==false)
    {
        $seutitulo = str_replace("Time", "Team Supply", $seutitulo);
    }

    echo $seutitulo;

?></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Voce pode criar um mapeamento das categorias, usando o nome da categoria que quer substituir como chave, e o nome novo como valor:

```
$categories = array(
  "Time" => "Team Supply"
);
```

E, ao recuperar a categoria, verificar se ela existe no mapeamento:

```
<?php
$cat = single_cat_title("", false);
if (isset($categories[$cat])) {
  $cat = $categories[$cat];
}
?>
<p><?php echo $cat; ?></p>
```

Repare que a funcao [single_cat_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/single_cat_title/) esta recebendo dois parametros:

- `""` - Prefixo da categoria
- `false` - Boolean indicando se a funcao deve apresentar a categoria (`true`) ou apenas retornar a categoria (`false`).

No caso, nao queremos nenhum prefixo, e tambem nao queremos que ele apresente a categoria, mas sim que a retorne, para podermos filtrar antes de apresentar.